# Graphs in 3d with Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, surface

**> how to plot a cone, a hyperbolic paraboloid  and a circular paraboloid

> ? , with the following equation:
>
> [enter image description here][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP28T.png**

Answer (score 0):

Use [surface plots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html):

```
a = ?; b=?; c=?;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,25), linspace(0,1,25))
Z = ((x/a).^2 + (y/b).^2)*c
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Replace `linspace(0,1,25)` by the range you want.

Comment: But I want to plot the tree types , how can I do ? Without functions

Comment: 1. Matlab is a functionnal language, so without function is going to be "difficult", all the functions here are available on a base matlab instalation. 
2. I don't know what a tree type is. In your question you asked "how to plot", so if you need something more specific, please rephrase your question. That's also the reason why you get downvoted. You can take some time reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask